# Why I get different language in debian console?

Tags: debian, locale, kde-plasma

Please help me to understand how debian(kde) decides what language to use in terminal (konsole).
My system language is English, but all requests in konsole (e.g.: password) I get on Russian. Why?
My locale:

```
LANG=en_IL
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:he
LC_CTYPE="en_IL"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IL"
LC_TIME="en_IL"
LC_COLLATE="en_IL"
LC_MONETARY="en_IL"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IL"
LC_PAPER="en_IL"
LC_NAME="en_IL"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IL"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IL"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IL"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IL"
LC_ALL=
```

If any additional info is needed, please ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `LANGUAGE=en_US:ru:he` to `LANGUAGE=en_US`

Answer (score 0):

By the below command it should work.

```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

From this English will become the default language of the debian console.